# 'Cannot access a disposed context instance error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly private IProductWriteRepository _productWriteRepository;
    readonly private IProductReadRepository _productReadRepository;

    public ProductsController(IProductWriteRepository productWriteRepository, IProductReadRepository productReadRepository)
    {
        _productWriteRepository = productWriteRepository;
        _productReadRepository = productReadRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async void Get()
    {
       await _productWriteRepository.AddRangeAsync(new()
        {
            new() {Id=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Test",Price = 300,Stock = 10,CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,},
             new() {Id=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Test 2",Price = 350,Stock = 20,CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,}
        });

       await _productWriteRepository.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

IProductWriteRepository:

```cs
public interface IProductWriteRepository : IWriteRepository<eCommerceAPI.Domain.Entities.Product>
{
}
```

IProductReadRepository:

```cs
public interface IProductReadRepository : IReadRepository<eCommerceAPI.Domain.Entities.Product>
{
}
```

IReadRepository;

```cs
public interface IReadRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> GetWhere(Expression<Func<T,bool>> method);
    Task<T> GetSingleAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> method);
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id);
}
```

IWriteRepository:

```cs
public interface IWriteRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    Task<bool> AddAsync(T model);
    Task<bool> AddRangeAsync(List<T> model);
    bool Remove(T datas);
    bool RemoveRange(List<T> datas);
    Task<bool> RemoveAsync(string id);
    bool Update(T model);

    Task<int> SaveAsync();
}
```

[image]

> Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this
> error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from
> dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context
> instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are
> calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using
> statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the
> dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances.

Comment: And `IProductWriteRepository` implementation?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: How is `IProductWriteRepository` set up in DI? What is the implementation of it, the concrete code that is being called. There's not enough information here to help you.

Comment: Need to see the implementation of your repository, not the interface..

Comment: Hi @Ahmet Selçuk Özdemir， which line you makes such error? Do you debug your code and check it? If it makes error in your implement class, pls also share the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public async void Get()
```

Your controller action is async, but returns `void`. So it will continue to run in the background, after the request scope has been disposed.

You need your routing endpoint to wait for the action to complete;

```cs
public async Task Get()
```

If you really want this request to run in the background, without forcing the client to wait, you should investigate some other solution.